# How to set a value with a for loop (for columns)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to set a value "Email_Sent" in a Google Sheets cell (row 28, column "j") if the value of row 4, column "j" is equal to the target_date. The script runs but it doesn't seem to set the value...

Here's the relevant section of my script:

```
 var vs2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Wor...").getRange("A4:28").getDisplayValues();
 for (j = 0; j < vs2.getLastColumn; j++) {
   if (vs2[4][j] === target_date) {
       Logger.log(vs2[4][j]);
       SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Wor...").getRange(28, startColumn + j).setValue(Email_Sent);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Is Email_Sent a variable or a string? It's not defined anywhere in your code. If it's a string,  it must be enclosed in quotes. Also, you don't call the 'getLastColumn' method. You must use round brackets like this getLastColumn()

Comment: Great catch. It's a string. I've added the quotes and called .getLastColumn(). Still no luck. Also, I've realized that I was calling ".getLastColumn()" from values rather than the range. Should I change that also? Are the vs2[4][j] values zero-based? That could screw with it too...

Comment: Yes, you should call getValues() on the instance of the Range object instead of the values array. JS arrays are zero-indexed, unlike rows in the spreadsheet. Be sure to learn the basics of JavaScript before your dive into Google Apps Script. It's also possible that your IF condition never evaluates to 'true'. Use Logger.log() to log each value and see what happens there

Comment: I figured it out. I was calling from [4][j] from the range (which started at A4). I forgot that the JS array was based on the range values, so A4 is [0][j]. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

There was a mistake on the `if` condition (Quote from the user):

> I was calling from [4][j] from the range (which started at A4). I forgot that the JS array was based on the range values, so A4 is [0][j].